# snowflake - parse_json

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a sql query in which i want to filter in where clause different rows following the next logic, for example:

> where   table1.field1 in (function1(:json_name))

So the function, function1 is defined as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS db.schema.function1(json_name VARCHAR) 
RETURNS TABLE(json_col VARCHAR) 
AS $$ 
DECLARE 
    exception1 EXCEPTION (-20001, 'Error'); 
BEGIN
    select parse_json(:json_name as src) src, lateral flatten(input => src) ) 
    where value is not null; 
END; $$;
```

But i'm getting errors like,

```
Syntax error:L compilation error: (line 3)
syntax error line 3 at position 4 unexpected 'exception1'.
syntax error line 3 at position 29 unexpected '-'.
syntax error line 3 at position 35 unexpected ','. (line 3)
```

thoughts?

Comment: Does the SELECT statement work on its own? Can you update your question with sample data and what you expect the function to return with that sample data as input?

Comment: don't have any sample data, but for now i'm calling the function with something like this: function1('["1"]') and i changed the data type in the parameter as json_name VARIANT. If i remove the DECLARE, BEGIN and END and only kept the select like this, select tab.value from table(flatten(input => parse_json(:json_name))) tab
    where tab.value is not null; the error changes to 002210 (0A000): SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 60
Bind variables not allowed in view and UDF definitions.

Comment: To clarify, if you run just the SELECT statement, and replace anything specific to a SP(like bind variables) with appropriate values so that you have a valid standalone SELECT statement, does it run successfully? BTW, if you read the documentation it clearly states that when a UDF is returning a table you need to declare the columns and their datatypes in the RETURNS statement

Comment: Is that supposed to be a snowflake function? why not use javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For snowflake I suggest using [javascript](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/stored-procedure/stored-procedures-javascript) such as this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION db.schema.function1(json_name STRING)
RETURNS TABLE(json_col STRING)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    var parsed = JSON.parse(json_name);
    var flattened = [];
    
    for (var key in parsed) {
        if (parsed.hasOwnProperty(key) && parsed[key] !== null) {
            flattened.push([parsed[key]]);
        }
    }
    
    return flattened;
$$;
```

And call it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.field1 IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(db.schema.function1(:json_name)));
```

You will need to correct the "db.schema" references, and you may want to include a "try/catch" for error handling e.g:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE db.schema.function1(json_name STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    var flattened = [];
    try {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(json_name);
        for (var key in parsed) {
            if (parsed.hasOwnProperty(key) && parsed[key] !== null) {
                flattened.push(parsed[key]);
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // handle error here
        return "Error: " + err.message;
    }
    return flattened.join(',');
$$;
```